# Accessing value from nested hash

Tags: ruby, hash

After collecting some information from a user on a Ruby on Rails application, I have:

```
params[:store] # => {"products"=>{"id"=>"89,90,91"}}
```

I need to extract the string `"89,90,91"`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: "What have you tried" is not allowed in comment.

Comment: Let `h1 = params[:store] #=> {"products"=>{"id"=>"89,90,91"}}`. Then `h2 = h1["products] #=>  {"id"=>"89,90,91"}}`. So `h2["id"] #=> "89,90,91"`. Putting that together, `params[:store]["products]["id"] #=> "89,90,91"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` here is a `Hash` object, which in Ruby, is a data structure that is a list of key-value pairs. For example, the following is a `Hash` object of key-value pairs:

```
user = { first_name: "Michael", last_name: "Chabon", occupation: "author" }
```

If you want to extract a value from `user`, you need to pass the key of the value you want. For example, say we wanted to get the value of the key `last_name` from `user`. We would simply call `user[:last_name]` which would return `Chabon`.

Similarly, we can nest hashes, which brings us back to your example. Let's look at the parent `Hash` `params` which probably looks something like this:

```
params = {:store=>{"products"=>{"id"=>"89,90,91"}}, . . . }
```

If we call `params[:store]`, it will return the following:

```
{"products"=>{"id"=>"89,90,91"}}
```

Now, since we are dealing with nested hashes, we can stack our keys. For example, if we call `params[:store]["products"]` we are returned the following:

```
{"id"=>"89,90,91"}
```

Now, since you are looking for `"89,90,91"`, we can stack `["id"]` to the above with `params[:store]["products"]["id"]`, which returns the following:

```
"89,90,91"
```

If you wanted to store that in a variable, you can just assign what we did above to a variable:

```
ids_as_string = params[:store]["products"]["id"]
```

Comment: Since Ruby 2.3.0, this can be done using `Hash#dig`: `params.dig(:store, 'products', 'id')`

Answer (score 0):

With the given example it is just:

```
params[:store]['products']['id']
#=> "89,90,91"
```